# LightSwitch HTML Client: How to set the value of a computed property based on another computed property

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, computed-field

Before asking my question, I make a simple example to make my question clear.

In my LightSwitch HTML Client, I have a table with one column: "amount"

I made a computed property, "amountPlusTax" and I set its value as follow,

```
myapp.BrowseTransactions.amountPlusTax_postRender = function (element, contentItem) {
        contentItem.dataBind("data.amount", function () {
            $(element).text(parseFloat(contentItem.data.amount) * 1.05);
        });
 };
```

As you see, amountPlusTax = amount * 1.05

The problem I have I want to make another computed property whose value depends on the value of "amountPlusTax" computed property. 
Like, amountPlusTaxPlusInterest = amountPlusTax * 1.03

How is it possible?

This doesn't work:

```
myapp.BrowseTransactions.amountPlusTaxPlusInterest_postRender = function (element, contentItem) {
    $(element).text(parseFloat(contentItem.screen.amountPlusTax) * 1.03);
};
```

Comment: what answer are you getting? is it displaying null or an incorrect value?

Comment: It's display null (nothing).

Comment: have you tried using a setTimeout function? it may not be calculating it in time which is an issue ive had, and i find that 250ms worked a treat..

Comment: I used setTimeout too but doesn't work. Probably the computed property value won't be available during the postRender time. Finally I decided to go with RIA.

Answer (score 0):

Although this doesn't directly answer your question, you could alternatively capture the Inserting/Inserted/Updating/Updated events in the DataService and update one or both of the fields instead of using computed properties.

For example:

```
partial void SomeTable_Updating(SomeTable entity)
    {
        if (entity.SomeField.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
            entity.SomeField = Utils.ConvertToValidName(entity.Name);
    }
```